# Cannot mount a volume without using sudo

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

The following command works and mounts the local volume:

```
sudo docker run -ti -v "$PWD/codebase/realsmart-saml-copy":/var/www/html realsmart-docker_smartlogin bash
```

The following command does not work and does not mount the volume

```
docker run -ti -v "$PWD/codebase/realsmart-saml-copy":/var/www/html realsmart-docker_smartlogin bash
```

For some reason, docker is only able to mount volumes using the `sudo` command, rendering our local docker environment useless on a colleagues laptop. The same docker-compose file works on my laptop (also a mac, same OS).

Any idea as to what the issue might be with his laptop configuration? Or indeed the docker setup.

(The code extract is to make clear the problem with mounting volumes, the same issue presents itself using a `compose.yml` file.)

Non working code:

```sh
docker run -ti -v "$PWD/codebase/realsmart-saml-copy":/var/www/html realsmart-docker_smartlogin bash
```

No error messages are displayed, but the results are not as expected as the volume does not mount without using sudo.

Comment: The way Docker works internally it’s very odd that `sudo` would make a difference here; the exact same HTTP request should get passed across to the privileged Docker daemon.  What specific evidence leads you to believe that the volume isn’t getting mounted?

Comment: Can you post the permissions on the volume (`ls -lad $PWD/codebase/realsmart-saml-copy`)? Does the docker unix permissions group have read access to it?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I've found that the machine isn't mounting the files within the /Users directory correctly. folders **are** being mounted, but the files are not being mounted, meaning that the volumes are being mounted correctly by docker-compose but the docker-machine doesn't contain the files. I'm stumped as to why the machine isn't showing the files unless created with sudo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for anyone interested.

After upgrading to Docker Desktop Boot2Docker has been replaced.

Steps to fix the issue:

docker-machine rm machine-name

unset DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY

unset DOCKER_CERT_PATH

unset DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME

unset DOCKER_HOST

restart Docker Desktop

cd path/to/docker-project.

docker-compose build
docker-compose up (or docker run)

project now available on localhost

Further details: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/docker-toolbox/

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if the user is part of the docker group.

It would make sense that sudo works, but not for the local user, if that local user is not part of the docker group.

Comment: I've checked this and everything appears to be A-OK, I've found that the machine seems to be the problem, the local filesystem (/Users) is being mounted into the machine, but the files are missing, for example; docker-machine ssh machine-name, cd /Users/username/www/docker/codebase/project works, the directory is there, but none of the files appear within the machine. This appears to be why the files cannot be mounted into the volume on compose up, because they aren't available within the machine. I can't workout why the directories would be mounted, but not the files.

Answer (score 0):

Add your user to the docker group.

`sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`